# How to populate inside array of array

Tags: node.js, angular-material, material-design, angular8

I want to access id's inside the `recordId`

```
[ { recordId:
     [ 5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d8c,
       5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d92,
       5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d95 ],
    isDelete: false,
    _id: 5ec278f6da31482240554476,
    createdAt: 2020-05-18T12:00:54.355Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-05-18T12:00:54.355Z,
    __v: 0 },

  { recordId:
     [ 5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d8c,
       5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d92,
       5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d95 ],
    isDelete: false,
    _id: 5ec276334e094223c84a398e,
    createdAt: 2020-05-18T11:49:07.691Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-05-18T11:49:07.691Z,
    __v: 0 },
...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataList = [
    { recordId: [`5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d8c`, `5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d92`, `5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d95`], isDelete: false, _id: `5ec278f6da31482240554476`, createdAt: `2020-05-18T12:00:54.355Z`, updatedAt: `2020-05-18T12:00:54.355Z`, __v: 0 },
    { recordId: [`5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d8c`, `5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d92`, `5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d95`], isDelete: false, _id: `5ec278f6da31482240554476`, createdAt: `2020-05-18T12:00:54.355Z`, updatedAt: `2020-05-18T12:00:54.355Z`, __v: 0 },
    { recordId: [`5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d8c`, `5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d92`, `5d836ceb2afc1764751f8d95`], isDelete: false, _id: `5ec278f6da31482240554476`, createdAt: `2020-05-18T12:00:54.355Z`, updatedAt: `2020-05-18T12:00:54.355Z`, __v: 0 },
]

dataList.forEach(item => {
    item.recordId.forEach(id_Item => {
        console.log(id_Item)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the object that you've shared looks like

```
let obj = [
   { 
      recordId : [ ]
      ...
   }
.....
]
```

One way to get the element will be using the index for the outside array and then for the nested array.

```
obj[ <index> ].recordId[ <index inside recordId> ]
```

You can use the loops to get access too. Taking an example

```
let obj = [
{
      "recordId":[
         "6d836ceb2afc1764751f8d8c",
         "6d836ceb2afc1764751f8d92",
         "6d836ceb2afc1764751f8d95"
      ],
      "isDelete":false,
      "_id":"5ec26f964cf6ec0520f5e53a",
      "createdAt":"2020-05-18T11:20:54.939Z",
      "updatedAt":"2020-05-18T11:20:54.939Z",
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

The following code gives access to each of the object in the parent array

```
obj.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
})
```

Now to get access of the inside recordId, following code can be used

```
obj.forEach(element => {
    element.recordId.forEach(id =>{
      console.log(id);
    })
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is very good for a first post. I especially appreciate the combination of explanation and code. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Jeremy